# FindBugs GUI not showing source code in upper right pane

Tags: findbugs

I am able to run the FindBugs GUI and even export result in XML using "Save As" option in "File" menu. I am able to see a description of the bug in the "Details" tab of the bottom pane when specific bug is selected. I am also able to apply filters and getting filtered output.

I am facing problem in exporting the result to HTML from "Save As..." option in "File" menu, as the generated HTML file is of Zero bytes and is blank. Also I am not able to view the program source code in the upper-right source-code pane. Any help what may be causing this?

Comment: Have you specified the path to the source code when creating new project?

Comment: I am using GUI, I browsed it and added it.

Answer (score 0):

First compile your code to get the class file. For example if you are using Eclipse, you should have a bin folder and an src folder.

- Open Findbugs
- Start a new project
- Add the bin folder to your classpath
- Add the src folder to the source files
- Analyze

I know that this is an old question but I just had this problem and couldn't find an answer anywhere